# Ubuntu Touch using apt-get

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, ubuntu-touch

I'm sorry if this has already been asked, I did do some searching and didn't find it. 
However a number of questions, I have just installed the latest Ubuntu touch, on a nexus 5, and was going to have a play with the terminal etc.

1) I notice the presence of apt-get, however when I try apt-get install telnet (so I can connect to an IRC) I get `Unable to write to /var/cache/apt` and `The Package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened`.

2) Is it possible to add other PPA's to my phone, and install normal Ubuntu packages(obviously within reason, things such as for example Apache, nmap, or console programs).

3) I see it has dpkg, what debs are supported, that i can install on here? Or would it be anything console, that the hardware supports?

Comment: Most PPAs only have packages for x86 architecture that won't work on a phone.

Comment: If this is the case, how would i be able install say an IRC client, or tellnet to use? Or would i want to write something in perl that does the same thing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [Installing Ubuntu on devices](http://developer.ubuntu.com/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/):

> **Enabling read-write mode**
>
> By default the system is read-only. You can switch to read-write mode,
>   although this disables Ubuntu system upgrades. The main purpose for
>   this is developing the Ubuntu system directly. This is not required
>   for developing apps or using the system normally. Recovering from
>   read-write mode is possible but requires reinstalling the system from
>   scratch.
>
> Warning: Switching a device to read-write mode (and/or recovering from
>   it) is an advanced feature and may result in complete data loss.
>
> Warning: Switching a device to read-write mode disables automatic
>   over-the-air updates.

Install on your host system the [phablet-tools](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/phablet-tools) package:

```
sudo apt-get install phablet-tools
```

And type the following command:

```
phablet-config writable-image
```

The system will reboot in read-write mode, but even if you'll be able to use apt-get or set up a PPA, only packages built for armhf will be installable.

Comment: So i can't use apt-get to any avail without doing this, i have to do it all via the software center?

Comment: @user3407675 You can't run apt-get on read-only images, only applications that you get from the Ubuntu Store are allowed

Comment: use this to make it writable:  sudo mount -o remount,rw /

Comment: @SylvainPineau How do I supposed to run `sudo apt-get install phablet-tools` for the first time if apt is disabled (because of read-only image)? Your answer is no really valid here.

Comment: @KhurshidAlam You need to install `phablet-tools` on your desktop/laptop system running Ubuntu. Then plug with a USB cable your device and run the `phablet-config` command. All those commands have to be run from your desktop. Once RW is enabled, then use `phablet-shell` to have a remote shell or the terminal app of Ubuntu-Touch to install packages with `apt-get`.

Comment: @SylvainPineau Ok. Thanks for the clarification.