# install ubuntu on google nexus10 without android

Tags: software-installation, tablet

I have a google nexus 10 that I deleted android from and installed ubuntu dev now I want to put read and write on it but the error msg is I don't have MTP so the computer won't talk to the tablet.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

To allow communication between your Nexus 10 and your host system you need to enable the developer mode on your device.

Go to System Settings -> About this phone -> Developer mode:

[image]

To set the Writable Image, please follow this [guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/536342/32239).